# Null String Value in SQLite Causing App to Crash - Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, android-studio

I have a SQLite database which I fetch data from based on the input from a user and then set EditText to display this information. Some of the columns in the database may be NULL and this seems to be causing my app to crash when calling the function. How do I check if the value is NULL and how do I assign it a non-null value such as "N/A" or simply ""?

This is my getter function:

```
    fun getWidth(flange: String): String {
    var width = "Test"
    val db = readableDatabase
    val select = "SELECT * FROM $FLANGE_TABLE WHERE $COLUMN_FLANGE = $flange"
    val cursor = db.rawQuery(select, null)
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            width = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_WIDTH))
    }
    return width
}
```

This is where I set the EditText:

```
        binding.flangeButton.setOnClickListener {
        flange = binding.flangeNumber.text.toString()
        val width = databaseHelper.getWidth(flange)
        binding.width.setText(width)
    }
```

Both of these sets of code work perfectly fine if there is a non-null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Elvis operator:

```
width = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_WIDTH)) ?: ""
```

By the way, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use a parameterized statement:

```
val select = "SELECT * FROM $FLANGE_TABLE WHERE $COLUMN_FLANGE = ?"
val cursor = db.rawQuery(select, flange)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Side note for anyone else who may see this. I had to make a small change to implement your solution for SQL injection attacks. rawQuery requires the selectionArgs to be an array so I had to add `val selectArgs = arrayOf(flange)` and then change to `val cursor = db.rawQuery(select, selectArgs)`